# How can I put a <span> inside a <text text-anchor=..>

Tags: html, css

[This CodePen is an example](https://codepen.io/ClaireLarsen/pen/XmVyVX?depth=everything&limit=all&order=popularity&page=4&q=text&show_forks=false)

My project generates different text coming from this span:

```
<span id="model-selection-value"></span>
```

Meaning, this is what I would like to acheive:

**ORIGINAL**

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 960 300">
        <symbol id="s-text">
            <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="80%">Montserrat</text>
        </symbol>
```

**MY GOAL**

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 960 300">
    <symbol id="s-text">
        <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="80%"><span id="model-selection-value"></span></text>
    </symbol>
```

But the code above only reads pure text, doesn't it? Any way around?

Comment: You would have to use JavaScript or jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Oh, would you be very kind to show me an example related to my situation? I am new into jquery

Comment: Edit. actually you can use `.html()`

Comment: You want to dynamically insert `<span id="model-selection-value"></span>` in between the text element correct?

Comment: Yes, Robert, correct. That is what I want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

First, [use a `tspan` within a text SVGElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan) to get bonus points for Semantic SVG.

The text content of your `tspan` can be set like so.

```
var textSpan = document.querySelector('#model-selection-value');

textSpan.textContent = 'Montserrat';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 960 300">
    <symbol id="s-text">
        <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="80%"></text>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// initialize jquery
$(function() {
    // select desired element
    var $text = $('text');

    // your element to insert
    var myElement = "<span id='model-selection-value'></span>";

    // insert your element
    $text.html(myElement);
});
</script>
```

Result:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 960 300">
    <symbol id="s-text">
        <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="80%"><span id="model-selection-value"></span></text>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am 99% sure I followed your steps correctly. I first tested the pure text <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="80%">Montserrat</text> and it generated correctly, then I added the jQuery to the script and the text dissapered (which it should), but as I added the "<text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="80%"><span id="model-selection-value"></span></text>" the text was back to normal again (no change). What could be wrong?

Comment: As you added what to what?

Comment: As I added the SPAN to my HTML, like in your result.

Comment: The script adds the span every time it runs. So it will remove and replace whatever is in the text element. With what is inside `var myElement`

Comment: I think maybe there is something going on with the jQuery code. Because the text worked before I pasted that one. Could that be the case? ( I understand that the text isn't working after I add the jQuery as it is replacing the text with the span , but the span content doesn't show )

Comment: I am not sure. Create a jsfiddle so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: By the way I am starting to belive that i made you misunderdstand me. What i want to achieve is to input the values that that SPAN generates (which generates different values/text based on different actions). The problem is that the text-anchor within the SVG can only read pure text (I think) and can't read a SPAN. That is why nothing shows when we add the jQuery

Comment: Just put in myvar what you want to insert.

Comment: Hi all. I am still having some problems. Where should I add "MyVar" and what should I add to it?

Comment: @Mykita I think that it would be best to ask a new question with your new updated code. Including your input, the output you are getting and the result you are looking for.